# Error during ssh server installation: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: server, ssh, dpkg, hadoop

I am trying to install openssh-server. Then at the end I am getting the error:

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-06 13:52:20 +04; 9ms ago
  Process: 17679 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up ssh-import-id (5.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.27) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'
Firewall reloaded
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use? I've just installed `openssh-server (1:8.0p1-6build1)` and connected to it via `ssh localhost` without any issues.

Comment: Your title is misleading. It is not surprising that you can't connect when you have not been able to install the server. Your question is about installing, not connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you dpkg log at `/var/log/dpkg.log`. That may give you more information.

Read through the post installation script and see if you can follow what it is doing. You can find it in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst`.

Check why the script failed:

```
dpkg --configure -D 777 openssh-server
```

Comment: i have run the command: sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd .. and it works fine.. but each time when i restart my pc, the directory /var/run/sshd disapears and again i get the error as above. why is it so?

Comment: That's probably sym linked to /run directory which is volatile tmpfs in memory so lost on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Then run:

```
ssh localhost
```